# How VerifyTextPresent command can be used in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

How i can write `VerifyTextPresent` command in selenium IDE, and what shall be its procedure like i am writing `VerifyTextPresent="welcome"` to verify a text is present, it is returning an error, am i writing in correct format?

Comment: Have you been on Selenium home page? The very first video explains this.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with takeshin... it is very simple. However for your benefit, I'm giving the answer which is given to another questions but can help you.

There are many ways you can achieve this, and which one you have to use varies depending on how your application behaves. There is no straight way to answer which unless we see the actual application.

There are many commands that can help you. verifyValue [image: verifyValue Example], verifyText, & verifyTextPresent, & assertTextPreset etc

Right click on the fields that has values to be verified... You will find an option ShowAvailableCommands in the context menu, move into that option , you will find various ways you can achieve what you wanted. Hope it helps...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) then select some text, right click and choose "check text is present" (or something similar).

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the COMMAND verifyTextPresent and in the TARGET put Welcome. Leave the VALUE field empty

In HTML format it would be:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>Welcome</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

NOTE: You don't need to put the text value insdide comas (")

Answer (score 0):

`verifyTextPresent` command is used to verify text present on the page or not.

```
<tr>
   <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
   <td>Here you can write text which you want to verify</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```